# Impossible to rename extension file

Tags: python, operating-system, python-3.6, rename

I am dealing with a list of file ending with this extension : .abstr.

My aim is to rename the files to txt format and extract text from those file and put it in dataframe.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('spr_train_plain/'):
    for file in files:
        filename, extension = os.path.splitext(file)
        os.rename(file, filename + ".txt")
```

error

```
[WinError 2] Le fichier spécifié est introuvable: 'Art.001.eng.abstr' -> 'Art.001.eng.txt'
```

I do not understand why I get this error ?

Comment: Try this: `os.rename('spr_train_plain/'+file, 'spr_train_plain/'+filename + ".txt")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`os.walk` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) states that

> (...)Note that the names in the lists contain no path components. To
> get a full path (which begins with *top*) to a file or directory in
> *dirpath*, do `os.path.join(dirpath, name)`(...)

so you should replace

```
filename, extension = os.path.splitext(file)
```

using

```
filename, extension = os.path.splitext(os.path.join(root,file))
```

Comment: The part with `os.rename(file, filename + ".txt")` should be changed too, otherwise you'll get something like `The system cannot find the file specified: 'something.extension' -> 'spr_train_plain/something.txt'`